# Allow reordering of grid columns in ExtJS 7 Modern

Tags: extjs, extjs7

We're in the process of upgrading our web application from ExtJS 6.0.2 Classic to 7.1.0. We would also like to switch over to the Modern framework in the process. However, there is some code that is using the BoxReorderer class, which is not available in the Modern framework. It is being used as a plugin on a grid to allow the columns to be reordered. Is there an equivalent class or way to allow the user to reorder the columns by dragging the header sections in the Modern framework, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Grid columns reordering by drag and drop is default feature in classic and modern. For example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/31l5

Comment: @arthur Good to know. It wasn't in an earlier version when that BoxRenderer class was put in for that purpose (at least in Classic) afaik. (Just tried it, and it turns out that it's available by default in 6.0.2 Classic, too.) Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reordering is the default feature in classic and modern toolkits: [fiddle showing simple grid with store](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/31l5)